# How to add list to dictionary by sequentially?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Example dictionary:

```
dictionary = {}
dictionary['a'] = 1
dictionary['b'] = 2
dictionary['c'] = 3
dictionary['d'] = 4
dictionary['e'] = 5
print(dictionary)
```

run this code 1st time:

```
{'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

2nd:

```
{'e': 5, 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 4, 'c': 3}
```

3rd:

```
{'d': 4, 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'e': 5, 'c': 3}
```

**My expected result:**

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}
```

or if my code is:

```
dictionary = {}
dictionary['r'] = 150
dictionary['j'] = 240
dictionary['k'] = 98
dictionary['l'] = 42
dictionary['m'] = 57
print(dictionary)
#The result should be
{'r': 150, 'j': 240, 'k': 98, 'l': 42, 'm': 57}
```

Because of my project the dictionary with 100++ lists will write to a file and it will easier to read.

P.S. sorry for my english and if my question title is not clear.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python's `dict` are unordered in nature. For maintaining the order in which elements are inserted, use [`collection.OrderedDict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Sample Run:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict

>>> dictionary = OrderedDict()
>>> dictionary['a'] = 1
>>> dictionary['b'] = 2
>>> dictionary['c'] = 3
>>> dictionary['d'] = 4
>>> dictionary['e'] = 5

# first print
>>> print(dictionary)
OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4), ('e', 5)])

# second print, same result
>>> print(dictionary)
OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4), ('e', 5)])
```

For writing it to the json file, you can dump the dict object to `string` using `json.dumps()` as:

```
>>> import json

>>> json.dumps(dictionary)  # returns JSON string
'{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4, "e": 5}'
```

As per the [`collections.OrderedDict()` document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

> Return an instance of a dict subclass, supporting the usual dict methods. An OrderedDict is a dict that remembers the order that keys were first inserted. If a new entry overwrites an existing entry, the original insertion position is left unchanged. Deleting an entry and reinserting it will move it to the end.

Comment: but if he want to print that to file at the end don't you think it will not be very useful, as it's an object not a convetional dictionary that would print out **JSON** structure when printed to file.

Comment: @harshil9968: In that case, use `json.dumps()`. Updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Read up on `OrderedDict`.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

It remembers the insertion order of the keys.